# Where does wordpress plug-in download monitor store the data we have uploaded through it?

Tags: php, wordpress

I just wanted to know, where does the wordpress plug-in 'download monitor' stores the files we have uploaded on our website through it. Like, I know we can access it through the the plug-in itself, but where is the data actually stored, do they have there own server? Or is all the data stored somewhere in our website only? And can we access it, outside of the plug-in?

Comment: Have you tried asking the developer directly about this? Or how about inspecting the source code of the plugin to learn how it handles downloads data?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately there was no response, will try inspecting the source code though, the thing is that, I mainly work with MERN stack but had to do some work for someone in wordpress.